# How can I break a paragraph into sentences with Vim?

Tags: vim, macros

By breaking into sentences I mean that each new sentence should start with a new line.

How to repeat `)i<CR><Esc>` to the end of the paragraph `}`?  (`<CR>` = <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

If I make a macro `)i<CR><Esc>` as "q", can I execute it until the end of the paragraph?

Answer (score 3):

```
vap:s/\. /.^M/g
```

- `vap` selects your current paragraph
- `:s/\. /.^M/g` replace all periods followed by a space with a period followed by a newline. (Note that to get that literal newline (`^M`) in the replacement expression, you'll have to type `<CTRL-V><CR>`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do a search and replace. I just wrote this out. It works, but you could probably do better.

```
:%s/\v[ ]*([^\.]*\.)/\1\r/g
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution, start in normal mode and type:

```
vip:'<,'>s/\n/ /|'<,'>s/\([.?!]\)\s/\1\r/g
```

Note that the first '<,'> will automatically be inserted on the command line when you press the ":" key after typing "`vip`" in normal mode.

The first substitute joins the paragraph into one line, then the "|" character delimits a second :-command within the same command line, and this time the "`'<,'>`" must be typed by hand.  The second substitute command replaces a period, question mark, or exclamation mark followed by a space with the matching symbol and a newline.

This won't catch instances where a sentence ends with a period/excalmation/question and a quote character, etc. but the pattern can be extended to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there is a very easy way of doing this using
`vim-macros`.

- First in `normal mode` press `q`, then any key, suppose that key is
  `a`. So you will see something at the bottom as `recording @a`.
- Now follow the key-sequence as `0)i<cr><esc>q` Now your macro is
  recorded.   This will break the paragraph at `.` .
- Now, repeat this macro as many times by pressing
  `N@a` in normal mode, where `N` is any number.

**Note**: You can choose any alphanumeric character to store your macro than `a`, this macro breaks the line at `.`, you can choose any column just replace `.` by any `N` of your choice.