# How to break a paragraph with footnotes via \autocite{} into sentences in nVim?

Tags: vim, macros, latex

This question is similar to [the one asked here](https://superuser.com/questions/275364/how-can-i-break-a-paragraph-into-sentences-with-vim).

I'm trying to figure out how to break paragraphs written in a TeX file in Nvim so that:

- any sentences with a citation (i.e. `\autocite[][]{}`) after them retain their citation after the paragraph's split into lines, rather than putting the citation on a new line
- any sentences beginning after a citation are split on to their own line rather than remaining on the same line with the `autocite` entry

For example, I might have this paragraph:

This is a sample sentence! And here's a sentence with a citation. `\autocite[For instance, see:][29]{@citekey1}` Here's another sample sentence? And yet another sentence with a citation. `\autocite[][104]{@citekey2}` And two more sentences! Here's the final sentence?

**NB:** the `vip` command below doubles up `\` to escape them as I run this off a keybinding rather than a macro. The `\\([.?!])\\)` component lists the 3 punctuation marks I terminate my sentences with.

Running `vip:s/\\([.?!]\\)\\s/\\1\\r/g<CR>` outputs:

```
This is a sample sentence!
And here's a sentence with a citation.
\autocite[For instance, see:][29]{@citekey1} Here's another sample sentence?
And yet another sentence with a citation.
\autocite[][104]{@citekey2} And two more sentences!
Here's the final sentence?
```

The obvious solution would be to put the final punctuation mark after the `autocite` command. This doesn't work for me because my university requires Chicago-style citations, which requires my footnotes to be after the punctuation mark.

Is there any way to adjust my macro so that I end up with:

```
This is a sample sentence!
And here's a sentence with a citation.\autocite[For instance, see:][29]{@citekey1} 
Here's another sample sentence?
And yet another sentence with a citation.\autocite[][104]{@citekey2} 
And two more sentences!
Here's the final sentence?
```

The reason I'd like to try to solve this issue is because I prefer to break up my paragraphs into sentences while editing. I'd like to keep the citations with their sentences to make editing (esp. swapping sentences around) easier. I can rejoin the sentences with `vipJ` after.

Many thanks in advance.